# Opening Full-Screen Processes From Tkinter Hangs First Time

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a game-launching menu in Python 2.6 which uses subprocess.popen() to run your selected game. My problem is that the first time I run any game from the menu, it hangs: I get an hour glass over my Python app, and the game which I launched does nothing. I an see the game's icon on the task bar, but clicking on it does nothing. I have to kill the game's process in Task Manager. After this happens once, I can then launch any game, including the one I just had a problem with, and it works fine. I can even exit from my Python app and re-run it, and I don't have the problem. But I will get this problem again after a reboot. I've narrowed the offending code down to:

```
import os
import subprocess
from Tkinter import *
def reportEvent(event):
    if event.keysym == "Alt_L":
        os.chdir("\\path\\to\\game")
        si = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
        si.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
        subprocess.Popen("game.exe",    startupinfo=si).wait()
root = Tk()
root.option_readfile("optionDB")
root.bind('<KeyPress>', reportEvent)
root.mainloop()
```

The following code does not have this problem (initializes TK but does not use its main loop):

```
import os
import subprocess
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.option_readfile("optionDB")
os.chdir("\\path\\to\\game")
si = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
si.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
subprocess.Popen("game.exe", startupinfo=si).wait()
```

I can use my launcher to open non-fullscreen (windowed) applications without this problem occurring. It only happens for full-screen games. Any ideas? Thank you.

Edit: Based on a suggestion below, I tried the same code with Python 3.4, but I still get the same behavior.

Comment: Try upgrading to a more recent version of Python. I have no reason to think that this will help specifically, but you should do it anyway ;-)

Comment: Not related to the problem but I would use the `cwd` argument of `Popen` instead of `os.chdir()`. The latter changes the working directory of your program which may have unwanted side effects.

Comment: I found a fix. I removed the wait() from Popen, so it stopped blocking. Apparently the problem was that reportEvent needs to return as soon as possible so TK.mainloop can continue mainlooping. Even though the game process was created, I guess there was still at least one more thing the mainloop wanted to do before the game could start. It seems to me then that I should never have been able to run a game from this menu, rather than the problem only manifesting once after a reboot. Regardless, it's working just the way I want now.

Comment: Without the wait you might create zombie processes, i.e. the operating system can't fully free the resources for the external process unless the return code is read by the parent process. You could `wait()` in a separate thread.